# Mageplaza Ajax search not working after remove .html prefix

Tags: magento2, ajax, search, mageplaza

After i removed the standard .html URL prefix from all URL's, the mageplaza ajax search module doesn't work propperly anymore. It shows me the right products but is linked to the old .html url. Response is 404.

I tried to reindex the catalog search but it didn't work. Does someone knows a solution for this problem?

For me it looks like I have to reset the search database or something.

Kind regards,
Nick

Comment: You can ask to Mageplaza support.

Answer (score 0):

Try performing a full reindex, and then flush the cache :

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento cache:flush
```

If you have some external cache (CDN, ...), clear it aswell.

*Note* : Be careful when removing the `.html` suffix from the URL on a production website, as it can have a **high** SEO impact.

Answer (score 0):

Run bin/magento mpsearch:reindex in the root of your install. It'll rebuild the index.

HTH, Tom